# How can I manage multiple OrderByDescending criteria?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get a list that order by three property that by priority is

1. ToDate
2. Number
3. RunDate

My code is here

```
MyList
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.ToDate)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Number)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.RunDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But the result is incorrect.

For example when `MyList` contains two elements: e1, e2 and e1.ToDate > e2.ToDate, the result is e2.

Which property should come first? The property with highest priority (ToDate) or lowest one (RunDate)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Fluent Nhibernate - it's purely LINQ.  I've edited the tags - suggest you (or someone else who has sufficient rep) edit the title as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suspect you really want:

```
MyList
.OrderByDescending(p => p.ToDate)
.ThenByDescending(p => p.Number)
.ThenByDescending(p => p.RunDate)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

`ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` are used to specify secondary orderings after you've provided a primary one using `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`.